# Can new items in Reminders.app be created with a fixed order using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, reminders

I would like to be able to add items to a list in Reminders in a specific order, using AppleScript.

Using the following script, however, adds the items in a different order each time I run it:

```
set my_reminders to {"item4", "item3", "item2", "item1", "item"}
tell application "Reminders"
    tell list "Reminders"
        repeat with the_name in my_reminders
            set this_reminder to make new reminder with properties {name:the_name as string}
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding a short delay after the reminder creation solves the problem:

```
set my_reminders to {"item4", "item", "item2", "item1", "item3"}
tell application "Reminders"
    tell list "Reminders"
        repeat with the_name in my_reminders
            set this_reminder to make new reminder with properties {name:the_name as string}
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This works, but I would describe it as a workaround, rather than solving the problem, as it makes the script very slow for a large number of items. I'll go with this method for the moment, but hopefully there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: To shorten the time problem because of the delay, you can probably shorten the 1 second down to .5 or even less. Just keep using smaller time lengths until the script stops working to find the lowest number you can use.